# Group Theory - Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the following groups $3\mathbb Z$ and $5\mathbb Z$ under the addition opertation. Let $h : 3\mathbb{Z}\to 5\mathbb Z$ be such that
$h(15)=45$. Can $h$   be a homomorphism?

**My approach**- For h to be homomorphism, $\forall$ a,b ∈  $3\mathbb Z$ and $\forall$ h(5*a/3),h(5*b/3) ∈  $5\mathbb Z$ , $h((5a/3)+(5b/3))=h(5a/3)+h(5b/3) $. There I took $a=6$ and $b=9$ and the resulting $h(5a/3)=10$ and $h(5b/3)=15$ which gives $h((5a/3)+(5b/3))=25$.

Is this enough to prove by this counter example that $h$ is not homomorphism?

Comment: Yes , this can be proved by counter example in case h can't be a homomorphism. But your counter example looks wrong. how did you calculate $h(5a/3) =10$ ?

Comment: $5a/3$ might not in $3\mathbb Z$, so you can't have $h(5a/3)$.

Comment: Besides the issue Bhaswat pointed out, your argument isn't presented very clearly. What do you mean by "$\forall h(5a/3), h(5b/3) \in 5\Bbb Z$"? You can't generally quantify over expressions like this. You seem to have the right idea, which is find some input value for $h$ that causes a problem, as suggested in Quang Hoang's answer, but it's definitely a bit confused.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $15 = 5\cdot 3$, if $h(15) = 45$, what's $h(3)$? Can it be an element of $5\mathbb Z$?